# How to get MAX using LINQ and string.Split() function

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have a list with the following QuestionNumber values:

```
"1.9"
"1.10"
```

and the following code:

```
string value = Questionquery.ToList().Max(q => q.QuestionNumber.Split('.').ElementAt(1));
```

The code above keeps returning 9 as the MAX value however i am trying to get it to return 10 because that section of the value is more than 9. Is this even possible? I am trying to mimic the number system in Microsoft word and testing to see if this is possible.

Comment: I'd suggest reading up on the `Version` class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`q.QuestionNumber.Split('.').ElementAt(1)` is a string, so `Max()` is comparing strings (by characters), not numbers.

You need to parse it as a number (using `int.Parse()`) before passing it to `Max()`.

Comment: Cant believe I missed that! Thank you